# What does it mean to not divide any term

Tags: divisibility

I am trying to solve the below [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=225)(Please don't solve it)

> The sequence 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105, 193, 355, 653, 1201
>   ... is defined by T1 = T2 = T3 = 1 and Tn = Tn-1 + Tn-2 + Tn-3.
>
> It can be shown that 27 does not divide any terms of this sequence. In
>   fact, 27 is the first odd number with this property.
>
> Find the 124th odd number that does not divide any terms of the above
>   sequence.

What does it mean `does not divide any terms`? Can you explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$27$ does not divide any terms" means it does not divide $31$ or $57$ or $105$ or ... and so on for all the numbers in that sequence. (I started that at $31$ because it clearly can't divide anything smaller than itself.)

Answer (score -1):

That mean find the 124-th number (equal $a(124)$ for example) verify : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \quad a(124) \nmid T_n$